# Adding Cocos2d to existing project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I would like to appologize in advance however I think this question is overlooked.  I have a project I have been working on and I would like to incorporate coco2d.  How can I implement the coco2d-iphone-2.0 download. All the tutorials I have tried have either been outdated or left me with errors.

I keep getting ARC Semantic Issue and ARC Restriction once I follow steps of other tutorials to add coco2d to an existing project.

Thus, could someone be so kind as to put a step but step approach to adding the latest  stable version of coco2d to an already existing project.

Sorry if this seems trivial.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be through cocoapods. have a look at this web site http://cocoapods.org/

Comment: have tried a lot and I cannot get this to work.  I copied over the files and I just get error that either say there is an arc error, or it cannot find a file.

Comment: You do not need to copy anything when using cocoapods. It is the coolest and easiest way to use 3rd party stuff in iOS and MacOSX