# Adding Cocos2d (2.0) to existing iPhone Project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

(Posting for **reference purpose only**. So I will answer right away)

I used Cocos2d 2.0 on Xcode 4.6.3.

I faced a 'Lexical or Preprocessor issue' about **kazmath/SomeFile.h** file not found.

Looked around but could find only outdated questions.
I added Cocos2d to iPhone project and will discuss the steps i have taken so that it can help people looking for doing this and facing issues...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Cocos2d to existing project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410886/adding-cocos2d-to-existing-project)

Comment: add kazmath to header search path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will point out the steps that I have taken , so someone can take a look

***Step 1.***

Create a test project in Cocos2d and find the “**libs**” folder in finder, and then just copy it into your project’s folder in finder. Then from finder, drag-and-drop the “**libs**” folder into Xcode’s “**Project Navigator**” sidebar and check the “add files to destination”.

***Step 2.***

In **Project > Targets > Build Phases > Link Binaries with libraries >** Hit the + and Check if following frameworks are there if not add them:

1. AVFoundation.framework
2. GameKit.framework
3. CoreText.framework
4. AudioToolbox.framework
5. OpenAL.framework
6. QuartzCore.framework
7. CoreGraphics.framework
8. UIKit.framework
9. Foundation.framework
10. OpenGLES.framework

***Step 3.***

In **Project > Targets > Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths**

Add (**quotes included**) this

**“(your Project's folder name in finder)/libs/kazmath/include”**

***Step 4.***

In **Project > Targets > Build Phases > Link Binaries with libraries > Compile Sources**

Select all files except classes that are your project already and hit enter and add the Compiler Flag **-fno-objc-arc**.

By doing that, hopefully all the Cocos2D files are now ARC-disabled.

Try to Build at this moment….

If there are issues then continue

***Step 5.***

Go to **Project > Targets > Build Settings > Linking > “Other linker flags”**

Add **-lz** and **-ObjC** .

Build again to check any issue still exists…

***Step 6.***

Go to **Project > Targets > Build Settings >Search Paths > User Header Search Paths**

Add this

**./(your Project's folder name in finder)/libs/kazmath/include**

Now try to build.. The issues might have gone by now.

I got help from the Coco2d forum and would like to thank the forum members..

[Cocos2d Forum Thread](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/adding-cocos2d-2-0-to-existing-iphone-project/)

I am a newbie in programming, so please don't be rough on me if there is any mistake.

Comment: please tell me how to create cocos2d project for iOS.